# ASP.Net ScriptManager -> ServiceReference Ajax calls - Can I catch Start and End Events?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have a WCF service locally in my ASP.Net 4.0 application.  I have the following in my MasterPage:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Services/AJAXDataService.svc" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Then on my page I have the following JavaScript code:

```
...
5 calls to the service to fill in drop downs and such
...

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    var service = new BOR.AJAXDataService();
    service.GetComplaintDetails(passed, FillComplaint, DefaultFailure, null);
}); // AjaxStop - Event - Everything is done, now load the Model
```

This happens in the Document Ready event after about 5 other ajax calls.  If I do NOT put this in the ajaxStop event, it works, but depending on database and network latency, it may not work because the **GetComplaintDetails** needs what comes back from each of the previous calls.

I found the ajaxStop method and thought it is exactly what I need.  But apparently the Microsoft/ScriptManager calls do not go through jQuery (of course) so that function is pointless.

**Q:**  Is there a way to intercept the being/end, start/stop events of each of the previous calls when using the ScriptManager reference?  I would rather do this than creating the long and wordy jQuery calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looking into it further I came up with a decent work-around.  It uses the ASP.Net Client Side Framework (Sys) to make it work.

I created a global variable:

```
var _ajaxCounter = 0;
```

I put the following code in my global/MasterPage Document Ready method.

```
if (Sys.Net.WebRequestManager != undefined) {
    Sys.Net.WebRequestManager.add_invokingRequest(WRMInvoke);
    Sys.Net.WebRequestManager.add_completedRequest(WRMCompleted);
} // if we have the Sys.Net namespace
```

Then in that .js file that gets loaded on every page, I have the two methods:

```
function WRMInvoke(sender, args) { _ajaxCounter++; }

function WRMCompleted(sender, args) {
    _ajaxCounter--;

    if ((_ajaxCounter == 0) && (typeof (SomeFinalMethod) != "undefined")) {
        Status_Saving(false);
        Status_Working(false);

        SomeFinalMethod();
    }
}
```

So now on a page where I need to make sure something happens AFTER everything else, I just have to define a SomeFinalMethod method like the following:

```
function SomeFinalMethod () {
    var passed = $("#hdnComplaintID").val();

    if (passed != "") {
        var service = new BOR.AJAXDataService();
        service.GetComplaintDetails(passed, FillComplaint, DefaultFailure, null);
    }

    SomeFinalMethod = undefined;
}
```

**Note the last line of the SomeFinalMethod**, it wipes itself out.  In some cases, this is unnecessary.  However, on my page, there are things the user can do that perhaps trigger other ajax calls and the last one would call this method again and create a loop.

For reference, check out this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384024%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article.

Hope it helps others out there.